# Unable to push from vs 2013 to Git using GitLab HTTP

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitlab

firstable i'm ask after i was look for direction about 2 days.
so any help will be appriciated.

The situation is that we use gitlab on:

> Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64)

We installed **GitLab** (the specific version is: **7.3.1 1660aa2**)

We trying to push commits via Visual Studio (we've tried 2013, 2015) but without seccessing.

In Git Bash every thing is good, but we want to improve the usage by use visual studio.
many highlights:

1. like i said in ssh it worked.
2. the address we put as origin was taken from the GitLab platform.
   [GitLab link generated structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI89n.png)
3. the error we recived is:

   > Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found). [here is the error msg from VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR9VY.png)
4. there is no proxy on the way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to connect with http in Git Bash?

I'm suggest to check.

Also try that stracture:

> {userNameInGitLab}@{yourSrvName}/{destRepository.git}

Comment: http in Git Bash i get "remote: Not Found" (same react).  But when i tried your struct i get Windows Security prompt to give user and password, and when i put them i get sucsses!!  So Thank a lot.